# Strange evaluation order using Python's splat (*) in MacBookM1

Tags: python, apple-m1, splat

I noticed a strange behavior while using the splat operator.

I ran the following code on different computers:

```
def func(m):
    m(1)
    return []
    
messages = []
print(
    [*messages, *func(messages.append)]
)
```

Test 1

- PC: MacBook Air M1
- Python version: 3.9.7
- Output: `[]`

Test 2

- PC: MacBook Pro Intel
- Python version: 3.8.9
- Output: `[1]`

Test 3

- Google Colab
- Python version: 3.7.12
- Output: `[1]`

Test 4

- Online interpreter: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/
- Python version: unknown
- Output: `[1]`

My first impression was that the splat was applied to `messages` before `m(1)` in Test 1, but after in the other tests. Since this doesn't seem to be associated to the Python version, I guess there's something different with the M1 chip...

I couldn't find a clear explanation of what should happen here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Comment: Which 3.10 version exactly? I was under the impression that 3.9 and newer would result in `[]`.

Comment: Would be good to do `print(
    [*messages, *func(messages.append)], sys.version
)` to be sure you're running the version you think you're running.

Comment: You are correct Kelly, version 3.10 also results in [], so the question was wrong.
The answer is the Python version as you suspected. Thank you for the response :)